# jQuery - back and next between multi select questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have to build a multi select questionnaire which the user can  go back to previous question and change the answer.

I want to ensure the following (for example):
The user in question number 2 and he clicks on the button "back"- how can I display the selected answer from question 1 as checked?

This is the code for creating the checkbox:

```
 $.each(multiQ[questionIndex].answers, function(key, val) {
            $('#answers').append('<label><input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="fooby[1][]" value="'+val+'"  onchange="test(this)" >' + val + '</label>');
```

Comment: Are you questions on the same page? Is it a single page application where you are using tabbed divs for question pages? There's not enough information to answer your question.

Comment: All the questions are in the same page and I change them dynamically. The data is taken from JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I will recommend you to use is [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). You can use this to save the answer for each question, then you can get the previous/next question's answer by giving a `key/value` on the button..

Here is an example how to use LocalStorage:

```
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object called questions, and store questions and questions answers in it.

It's structure will look like this:

```
{
    0: {
            text: "Who is the president of USA",
            options: ['Obama','Obama','Obama','Obama'],
            correctOption: 3,
            userAnswer: 2
    },
    1: {
            text: "Who is the president of USA",
            options: ['Obama','Obama','Obama','Obama'],
            correctOption: 3,
            userAnswer: 2
    },

}
```

And store current question number in another variable (for example, called 'step' ). When a user clicks next button increase the step variable and render question which you take from questions object (do the same when user clicks back button).When a user select an answer write it to questions object in order to store it. In this way, you can display the question and users answer easily.

Edit:

I have made an example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/oxzp88ub/3/

It's very simple example to show the basics of displaying question.

Comment: How am I supposed to update the userAnswer and display the answer as checked?

Comment: I have updated the example, it is much better now :) http://jsfiddle.net/oxzp88ub/3/